# Lua get first N elements of a table

Tags: lua

Is there a method for getting the first N elements of a table? And more generally, give me the first N elements starting from position P.

Or do I have to write a function and use `pairs` to do so?

Comment: There is [table.move](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.move) in Lua 5.3 for obtaining slice of array as new array.  And there is `table.unpack` for obtaining slice of array as a tuple

Comment: That was great; wanna post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer?

Comment: BTW—In particular, `pairs` doesn't use an order because, in general, a table doesn't have an order. You probably mean positive integer keys, of which a ["sequence"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) is a special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments tables don't have an order by default. It's just a bunch of key value pairs. So your request only makes sense for sequences. Here's some detail and an example for each suggested solution.

```
local myTable = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}

local p = 3
local n = 4
```

Option 1: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack

> ```
> table.unpack(list [, i [, j]])
> ```
>
> Returns the elements from the given list. This function is equivalent
>   to
>
> ```
> return list[i], list[i+1], ···, list[j]
> ```
>
> By default, `i` is `1` and `j` is `#list`.

```
print(table.unpack(myTable, p, p+n-1))
```

> c  d  e  f

Option 2: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.move

> ```
> table.move (a1, f, e, t [,a2])
> ```
>
> Moves elements from table `a1` to table `a2`, performing the
>   equivalent to the following multiple assignment: `a2[t],··· =
>   a1[f],···,a1[e]`. The default for `a2` is `a1`. The destination range
>   can overlap with the source range. The number of elements to be moved
>   must fit in a Lua integer.
>
> Returns the destination table `a2`.

```
local slice = table.move(myTable, p, p+n-1, 1, {})
```